# Messagebox centered to parent Window / Form

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to build my own HTA right now to act as a front end for some of my batch scripts. I would like to use a msgbox (or anything equivalent) that I can use to output any errors, clicking Ok will just get rid of the prompt.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
x=msgbox("Error text" ,48, "Error: Title")
```

I would preferably like the following conditions, to be able to use a custom icon, the box to center on X and Y to the parent window/form, and to allow me to define the text in the box and it's title.

If this is not possible then just a messagebox that can be centered on X and Y to the parent window would suffice.

Is there any way of doing this in VBScript?

Or should I look into doing an HTML/CSS version that would popup on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your first question, but whatever the answer is there must be necessarily limits to what a box message box that pops up outside of the HTML can do.

So for customization that includes icon, centering and anything else expressible in HTML/CSS, I think you should do HTML/CSS that pops up on the screen.

You might want to look at jqueryui or bootstrap to get you going faster so you don't have to start from scratch.

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

They both use jquery underneath so if you aren't already using it, you'll pick up some more bytes in your initial download.